# GridDB Go Client Bulk Insert Performance Degradation: Identifying Bottlenecks and Optimizing Data Loading

Tags: griddb

```
package main

import (i
    "fmt"
    "github.com/griddb/go-client/gs"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // GridDB connection settings
    factory := gs.GetFactory()
    gridstore, err := factory.GetGridStore(gs.NewGridStoreInfo("your_cluster", "your_database", "your_username", "your_password"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error connecting to GridDB: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer gridstore.Close()

    // Simulate bulk data loading into GridDB
    startTime := time.Now()
    batchSize := 10000
    totalRecords := 1000000 // One million records
    recordCount := 0
    for recordCount < totalRecords {
        container, err := gridstore.GetContainer("your_container")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error retrieving container: %v\n", err)
            break
        }

        // Generate and insert batch of data
        bulkData := generateBulkData(batchSize)
        if err := container.PutMultiple(bulkData); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error inserting data: %v\n", err)
            break
        }

        recordCount += batchSize
        fmt.Printf("Inserted %d records\n", recordCount)
    }

    elapsedTime := time.Since(startTime)
    fmt.Printf("Bulk data loading completed in %v\n", elapsedTime)
}

func generateBulkData(batchSize int) []interface{} {
    // Simulate data generation for the bulk insert operation
    // ...

    // Return a batch of data to insert
    return bulkData
}
```

I’m facing a significant performance degradation issue when performing bulk inserts into GridDB using the Go client. The provided code simulates a bulk data loading scenario where I’m inserting a large number of records into a GridDB container. Despite my efforts, the data loading process is slower than expected, and I suspect there might be bottlenecks in the code or suboptimal configurations.

Performance Degradation Issue: The code simulates bulk data loading, but the insertion rate is slower than anticipated. I suspect there might be performance bottlenecks or suboptimal settings affecting the bulk insert operation. How can I identify and address these performance issues to achieve faster data loading?

Bulk Insert Optimization: Are there specific optimizations or techniques I can apply to the code to enhance the bulk insert performance in the GridDB Go client? This includes batch size tuning, parallel processing, or any GridDB-specific configurations that can accelerate data loading.

Data Generation and Insertion: The generateBulkData function is a simplified representation of data generation. What are best practices for efficiently generating and inserting large batches of data into GridDB, especially when dealing with complex data structures or data transformation requirements?

Monitoring and Profiling: What tools or approaches can I use to monitor and profile the bulk insert operation in the GridDB Go client? Are there specific metrics or diagnostic methods to identify performance bottlenecks or resource utilization patterns?

Advanced Code Scenario: I’ve provided an advanced code scenario that simulates the bulk data loading process. Please review the code and provide insights, code modifications, or GridDB-specific optimizations that can help resolve the performance degradation issue and achieve efficient bulk data loading.

I’m seeking expert guidance on troubleshooting and optimizing bulk insert performance in the GridDB Go client for handling large datasets. Your expertise in diagnosing performance bottlenecks and suggesting improvements would be invaluable.